# SQL query causing problems with my load more posts function

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to add to my load more posts query below the following line

```
OR p.posted_to='$userid'
```

but when i add in the OR statement, to the query below, it returns results, but it just keeps repeating the same posts, every time i click load more, instead of loading older posts.

if i add this OR statement to my regular show posts, it does what it is supposed to do. the only issue arises when i am adding the OR statement to the loadmore posts query below.

```
$sql = "SELECT p.body, p.user_id, p.posted_to, p.post_likes,p.stamp, p.id,u.username,     u.imagelocation 
        FROM posts p 
        INNER JOIN users u 
        ON p.user_id=u.id 
        WHERE p.user_id='$userid'   
        AND p.id <'$lastcomment' 

        ORDER BY p.stamp DESC
        LIMIT 0,3";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you wrote something like this:

```
WHERE p.user_id='$userid' OR p.posted_to='$userid'
AND p.id <'$lastcomment'
```

This doesn't work because AND has higher precedence than OR. You need parentheses.

```
WHERE (p.user_id='$userid' OR p.posted_to='$userid')
AND p.id <'$lastcomment'
```

Without the parentheses it will be interpreted as follows:

```
WHERE p.user_id='$userid'
OR (p.posted_to='$userid' AND p.id <'$lastcomment')
```

Comment: Thanks so much. This worked like a charm, and I never would have thought of it.